# How can I make colors in Adobe Illustrator line up more closely with colors on the iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, graphics, adobe-illustrator

Images with vibrant purple colors in them look washed out and faded on the iPhone 4's screen. This effect happens with other colors too. Also, purples in Illustrator look almost blue on the phone. I should add that I don't really have this problem when viewing the images on an iPhone 3g.

EDIT: Has anyone else had a marked color difference between Illustrator/Photoshop and the iPhone 4?

Answer (score 2):

Take care that 3G/3GS/4 doesnt have same display components and consequently not the same colors. Got 4 devices, lining them with brightness at maximum reveals impressive differences...

And even for one model there are variations depending I guess on production site/date...

Comment: I can understand differences between various models. Have you had big differences between Illustrator/Photoshop and the iPhone 4?

Comment: My iPhone 4 retina screen looks close to photoshop, I would even say that might be the most close one (in comparison with previous models). BUT my answer was to warn you that there are great chances that our iPhones 4 doesn't share the same screen panel and therefore same colors...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the iPhone 4's screen color profile is supposed to be standard sRGB, but in the end that doesn't mean much, as you've experienced.

You can easily get a constant live view of how your colors will look while you choose them via the free app **[LiveView](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/liveview/id301069270?mt=8)**. On your computer move the (free Mac or PC software) viewpoint over your mockup/drawing/whatever and you'll see that area mirrored on your device, giving you the ability to determine exactly what effect your adjustments are having.

Comment: This is a really useful app. But I used it and it only highlighted my problem further: colors look TOTALLY different between illustrator and the iPhone 4 (i.e. purple becomes blue).

Comment: purple become blue? have you checked your screen brightness? Make sure to set it at the default middle value, iPhone brightness saturates colors I think.

Comment: @lex You might also consider your monitor's calibration: are you sure it's solid?

Comment: I'm not sure. I have a 2011 macbook pro with a non-glossy display, and the color display profile is set to Color LCD in System Preferences. Should it perhaps be set to something else?

Comment: I suggest calibrating it. In the Displays system preference click "Calibrate" and **be sure to check the "Expert Mode" checkbox** where you'll be able to make real adjustments to the color. At the end of the process you'll be prompted to save the name of your new profile, and after doing so you can pull up your image in Illustrator and swap back and forth between the default and your adjusted profiles to see if it has a meaningful effect. While it would seem like LCDs would have pretty standardized color, they can actually vary widely (not as widely as CRTs, but still more than you'd think).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an excellent post on setting up correct color profiles in both Photoshop and **Illustrator**:

[Setting up Photoshop for web and iOS development](http://bjango.com/articles/photoshop/)

Comment: I had actually found this site before and it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

`Shift + CTRL + K` opens colorsettings for displaycolors in photoshop.
Maybe you can adjust them to the same colorfeeling