# Colors not matching in Illustrator and iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicolor, adobe-illustrator

I am making an icon with RGB color 186 186 186 in illustrator, and I have set the background color to the same. However, they appear to be different shades when I test the app!

Is there something I have to to do with the color profile?

I have tried this link:
[How can I make colors in Adobe Illustrator line up more closely with colors on the iPhone 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624572/how-can-i-make-colors-in-adobe-illustrator-line-up-more-closely-with-colors-on-t)

But it does not help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read this article: http://bjango.com/articles/photoshop/. I was going to suggest that then saw that the stackoverflow post you linked to links to that.

Answer (score 3):

I've had similar issues and what I use at least for Photoshop is I use something like Developer Color Picker (Free: http://www.panic.com/~wade/picker/) or Colors (Free: http://mattpatenaude.com/) But here are some other possible issues:

- In illustrator check the color mode you are using here: File > Document Color Mode
- If you are changing the image to jpg, png, etc. check your default color profiles I know there is an option to check ICC Profile while saving for web in Illustrator.

If you're having issues like this across the Adobe suite in Adobe Creative Suite 2, you can use Bridge to synchronize your color settings across all of Adobe apps.

Hope this helps.